# Is it possible to use `event.preventDefault()` with a `select` element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dropdowns which are dependent on other dropdowns.

I decided to calculate the dependencies on click, except it has a nasty side effect of showing option elements, then they quickly disappear and the dropdown list resizes.

I wondered if I could use `event.preventDefault()` on click, and then call the `click()` event manually after I have calculated the possible options.

It didn't seem to work.

What is the best way around this?

Here is my jQuery

```
var $selects = $('form#main select');


$selects.click(function(event) {
    var $thisSelect = $(this);
    event.preventDefault(); // Doesn't cancel anything

    // Get the other selected values
    var selectedIndexes = [];
    $selects.not($thisSelect).each(function() {
        var index = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
        selectedIndexes.push(index);
    });

    // I think this is where the problem lies -
    // it is my lazy way of showing them all again before I hide
    // what needs to be hidden
    $selects.find('option').show();

    // Remove them from this dropdown
    $.each(selectedIndexes, function(i, index) {

        $thisSelect.find('option').eq(index).hide();

    });

}).click();
```

Thanks!

### Update

Sorry for any confusion, you can see this behaviour on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/afudo3/edit).

You can not select one from the other - i.e. they can never have the same value.

In my Firefox 3.6.6, you will see the ugly jump between it calculating what it may display.

I realise for 2 `select`s only I could use `.siblings().hide()`, but it won't work if I need more than 2 (which I will later).

My ideal behaviour would be to click the `select` and have it show with no jump the available options. I think maybe my `show()` is the culprit, however it keeps the code simple.

Comment: I'm confused on what you are trying to achieve... been reading it over and over for 5 minutes now...

Comment: @Reigel I've set something up on JSBin to demonstrate, am editing question now. Thanks.

Comment: Showing/hiding options doesn't work in anything but Firefox, I believe.  Certainly not in IE.  I'd suggest simply generating the options based on the other selects either from a javascript array of possible options on the page or via an AJAX call to the server, then replacing the content all at once.

Comment: how about disabling? like this, http://jsbin.com/afudo3/2/

Comment: @Reigel That works OK, but it won't be good for my time selector dropdown (which lets you input from 00:00 to 23:45 in 15 minute increments). In that scenario, I'd rather show the only valid options (to keep the list smaller). Thanks for your comment too.

Comment: I tried using `select option[disabled=disabled] { display: none; }` in CSS but it wouldn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure that i am fully understanding your question. but this may work for you.
If you have problems, i will be glad to help you, but i would need a better explanations.

- **http://jsfiddle.net/kn73G/**

**HTML**

```
<select id="left">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select id="right">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var left = $("#left");
    var right = $("#right");

    left.change(function(){
        if (right.val() == $(this).val()) {
            alert("error");
            $(this).attr("selectedIndex", "0");
        }
    });

    right.change(function() {
        if (left.val() == $(this).val()) {
            alert("error");
            $(this).attr("selectedIndex", "0");
        }
    });
});
```