# Suppress default dropdown functionality with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I thought this would work but it doesn't, what am I missing?

html

```
<select id="TaskId">
 <option>A list of options</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#TaskId").click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: and your goal here is...what?

Comment: Why not simply remove options ? What are you trying to make ?

Comment: See this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176812/is-it-possible-to-use-event-preventdefault-with-a-select-element-with-jque

Comment: Are you using Firefox? You may not get this to work at all, , apparently this is still [an open bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=392863)

Comment: @acconrad - I read the open bug. I would like to have all platforms be supported so yes, Firefox is a major requirement. There is an answer below using `.mousedown` which is a good idea but as you state, does not work with firefox.

Comment: @acconrad - I got it to work in firefox. :D

Comment: I accomplished this by robbing the user of their click event. The trick was getting it to work while they were holding down the mouse click.

Answer (score 2):

e.preventDefault doesn't work at click context for dropdown, use this:

**Code 1:**

```
$("#TaskId").mousedown(function(){
   return false;
});
```

You can use this too:

**Code 2:**

```
$("#TaskId").mousedown(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Warning: e.preventDefault() has bugs for event handling in Firefox and Opera.**

This could be a kind of solution for what you trying to achieve:

**Code 3:**
Just play with:

```
$("#TaskId").prop('disabled', true);
$("#TaskId").prop('disabled', false);
```

**Code 4:**
If you don't want to disable all event handling, take a look at this example that could help:

**DEMO for Code 4:** http://jsfiddle.net/AHEex/

**DEMO for Code 1 and 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/JcpPU/

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't work for Firefox. As stated above, this may be a bug with firefox and therefore is not a fault of your code.

Comment: @TravisJ Yes, you are right, take a look at my possible solution, I edited my post.

Comment: @TravisJ I looked that you don't want to disable all event handling, maybe my last example could help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply disable the select field? It will both result in the desired behaviour and show the user what happened. Instead of installing click listeners, just

```
$("#TaskId").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, I like the idea of showing the user what happened so +1 for that. However, disabling the property will unfortunately disable all event handling for that element which is definitely not ideal.